# What is the max and min interval of numpy.random.normal() function?

Tags: python, numpy

The numpy.random.random has an interval b/w 0.0 and 1.0 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random.

Similarly what is the interval of the numpy.random.normal function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Answer (score 2):

## The basics

If you don't feed it any parameters, `np.random.normal()` will draw from a [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution), which has a `mean` of `0` and and a `std` (standard deviation) of `1.0`.

## The odds that any given value will lie outside of an interval

Regards of the parameters of the distribution, you can calculate the odds that a value will lie beyond `mean +/- z` (where `z` is any arbitrary value) with the following function:

```
import scipy.special as sps

def oddsbeyond(z, std=1):
    return 1 - sps.erf((z/std)/2**.5)
```

See the [wiki article on the error function `erf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Applications) for more details about the above function.

Here's a "table" with the odds that a value will lie outside of `mean +/- z*std` for `z = (0, 1, ..., 9)`:

```
print(np.array([np.arange(10), oddsbeyond(np.arange(10))]).T)
```

Output:

```
[[0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 3.17310508e-01]
 [2.00000000e+00 4.55002639e-02]
 [3.00000000e+00 2.69979606e-03]
 [4.00000000e+00 6.33424837e-05]
 [5.00000000e+00 5.73303144e-07]
 [6.00000000e+00 1.97317529e-09]
 [7.00000000e+00 2.55961918e-12]
 [8.00000000e+00 1.22124533e-15]
 [9.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]
```

So `95%` plus of values will lie within `2.0` standard deviations from the mean, and by the time you get to `9.0` standard deviations from the mean, the fraction of values beyond that is so small it's under the limit of what can be easily expressed using `double` values (the standard Numpy `float`).

Answer (score 1):

For normal distribution, any values more than 10 standard deviations away from the average are highly unlikely, but not impossible. And values more than 20 standard deviations away are *extremely* unlikely, but still not impossible.

Height of humans for example is similar to normal distributed, but not exactly, since a height less than zero is impossible. For normal distribution, it would be possible, just very unlikely.